# Access object property using variable in bracket notation in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have object with interface and I would like to dynamically access values by property key.

```js
const tmpUser: IUser = {
    username: "test",
    namespace: "test",
    password: "test"
}

Object.keys(tmpUser).forEach(property=>{
    // Error: Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'IUser'.
    console.log(tmpUser[property]);
})

// works
console.log(tmpUser["username"]);

// works
const someKey = "username";
console.log(tmpUser[someKey]);
```

also `tmpUser.hasOwnProperty(property)` doesn't help neither.

Comment: instead of `forEach(property =>` , try `forEach((property: keyof IUser) =>`

Comment: @MikeS. that won't work because `Object.keys(tmpUser)` is already `string[]`, so `forEach` expects a callback whose first parameter is `string`: `Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"username" | "namespace" | "password"'.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `Object.keys` does not allow use to pass a generic type, its return type is `string[]`, if we want to have type `[keyof IUser]` we can cast it

```
const keys: [keyof IUser] = Object.keys(tmpUser) as [keyof IUser]
keys.forEach((property)=>{
    console.log(tmpUser[property]);
})
```

BUT: It's is unnecessary. If you want to get key and value of that key you can simply use

```
Object.entries(tmpUser).forEach(([key,value])=>{
   
})
```

Answer (score 2):

You can specify that the `IUser` keys will be of type `string` (or if you want e. g. `string | number`):

```
interface IUser extends Record<string, any> {
    username: string
    namespace: string
    password: string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Throwing another solution here, especially since I'm assuming you'll have some kind of a `process` function that takes in an object and does something with it:

```
const process = <O extends { [key: string]: any }>(object: O) => {
    Object
        .keys(object)
        .forEach(prop => {
            // No longer complains
            console.log(object[prop]);
        });
}

process(tmpUser);
```